# Is this bad callback practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and repeatedly find myself writing methods in a helper object which take in a callback as a parameter e.g.

```
var utilities = {
    getTweets: function (user, maxTweets, callBack) {
            var obj = $(this);
            $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?&screen_name=' + user + "&count=" + maxTweets, function (data) {
                callBack(data);
            });
    };
```

I then call it like so:

```
 utilities.getTweets("TESTUSER", 4, function (tweets) {
                .....
             });
```

Given I am calling the code above using setInterval is this likely to leak over time/is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're doing is mostly fine, except that there's no need to create the extra closure.  Passing a closure written like:

```
function (data) {
      callBack(data);
}
```

is just the same as passing `callBack` directly in the parameter list.

However if you can guarantee running with jQuery 1.5 or later, then a better method is to just have `getTweets()` return the JQXHR object, and then you can use "deferred" methods in the client code:

```
var utilities = {
    getTweets: function (user, maxTweets) {
        var uri = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?';
        var data = {
            screen_name: user,
            count: maxTweets
        };
        return $.getJSON(uri, data);
    });
};
```

and then in the client code:

```
utilities.getTweets(user, maxTweets).done( /* your callback here */ );
```

In this way you can completely decouple the callback from the implementation.  Indeed you can register *multiple* callbacks, and error handlers, all without touching the implementation of `utilities`.

NB: use of a map for `data` above also protects your code against parameter injection.

Comment: +1 Nice one - after posting I spotted the extra closure; the use of deferreds is also a nice touch.

Comment: @Sidebp yeah, I was late noticing the extra closure too - edited that in after.

Comment: @Sidebp note also that using deferreds exposes functionality (e.g. error handlers) that `$.getJSON()` doesn't support in its own parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

If you're afraid of the memory overhead of creating that function every time, then do something like:

```
utilities.getTweets("TESTUSER", 4, utilities.handleTweets);
```

And in `utilities.handleTweets` you do as you do in the callback.

Answer (score -2):

You could use something like this:

```
var utilities = {
    options: {
         user: 'value',
         maxTweets: '4'
    }
    getTweets: function() {
        // access a value
        this.options.user;
    }
}
```

Or it would be best to create a proper plugin with options etc. Have a read of this article, it should be exactly what you need:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-set-default-settings-in-your.html

Comment: why want to make plugins everywhere? besides, the question here is more related to callback handling and implementation.

Comment: IMHO that's poor design - options should be for persistent state (e.g. a base URL?) - not for parameters that change on every function call.